# Dynamic page not being created

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I am successfully creating my Years pages. When I call /Years/1956 it is creating and rendering the page.

Here is my Years.cshtml.cs:

```
using Alpha.Data;
using Alpha.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace Alpha.Pages {
    public class YearsModel : PageModel {
        private AlphaContext context;

        public IEnumerable<GameSummary> GameSummaries { get; set; }
            =Enumerable.Empty<GameSummary>();

        public YearsModel(AlphaContext ctx) {
            context = ctx;
        }
 
        public IActionResult OnGet(string Year) {
            if (@Year is null)
                return new RedirectToPageResult("Index");
            else
                GameSummaries = context.GameSummaries.Where(s => s.DateTime.Year.ToString() == @Year);
                return new PageResult();
        }
    }
}
```

I am now trying to create my Opponents pages. Below is my code for Opponents.cshtml.cs.

The first part of the if statement is executing properly. If I call /Opponents without an argument, it redirects to OpponentsIndex. But, when I try to call a specific opponent, /Opponents/Centerville, I'm getting a 404 Page Not Found.

```
using Alpha.Data;
using Alpha.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace Alpha.Pages {
    public class OpponentsModel : PageModel {
        private AlphaContext context;

        public IEnumerable<GameSummary> GameSummaries { get; set; }
            =Enumerable.Empty<GameSummary>();

        public OpponentsModel(AlphaContext ctx) {
            context = ctx;
        }
 
        public IActionResult OnGet(string Opponent) {
            if (@Opponent is null)
                return new RedirectToPageResult("OpponentsIndex");
            else
                GameSummaries = context.GameSummaries.Where(s => s.Opponent == @Opponent);
                return new PageResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What’s your @page directive look like in the cshtml file?

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! If you want to put it in as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @BenderBoy That fixed it, thanks! If you want to put it in as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.